# What's special about abstract entities?

Tags: core-data

I checked the check button of `Abstract Entity` on one of my entities. I added a subentity to that entity. I verified at runtime that the corresponding `NSEntityDescription`'s `isAbstract` is `true`.

However, opposite to the statement "only concrete subentities can be instantiated" from the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html), I can still create `NSManagedObject`s of that abstract entity without any issues. I also checked the `sqlite` file and found nothing special about the table of that entity. Actually, the schema is exactly the same no matter whether it is abstract or not.

So, what's the effect of an entity being abstract?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html

Comment: @Desdenova The only relevant info in that doc is "only concrete subentities can be instantiated" which is not true in my test and is exactly why I am asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking entities abstract has no effect at all since the very beginning:

> [@numist](https://twitter.com/numist/status/1163644330600308736): @an0 isAbstract not affecting anything is behaving as implemented